# Shared variable keeps getting lost after some hours

Tags: php, shared-memory

I'm using the shm_ functions to provide a shared array to an API of mine. 
The array stores client data which helps to throttle incomming requests (rate limiting etc)
I run PHP 5.2.6-1 with suhosin patch

Here is the code, it might actually be useful to someone who's looking for code to create/read/write/store shared memory data in PHP.

```
$shm_key=ftok(__FILE__, 'S' ); 
$data=shm_attach($shm_key,500000);
$ar=shm_get_var($data,"variable");
if ($ar === FALSE))
{
// this should rarely ever happen !
// recreate empty arry
}
//...
// reading and changing the $ar array contents
//...
shm_put_var($data,"variable",$ar);
shm_detach($data);
```

The serialized variable data is rarely ever larger than 10-11kb, so 500kb should be plenty of free space.
In total there 10,000-50,000 of php script calls per hour.

The ($ar === FALSE) is hit 4-5 times a day resulting in a complete loss of all throttling data.
I've accepted this behaviour for years but would still like to see it solved.

My guess is that it's either a bug in shm_ or a race condition when writing/reading and multiple clients call the script at the same moment.

Comment: Have you tried checking with `shm_has_var` whether or not PHP thinks the value exists at all?

Comment: Are you sure your HTTP server is not getting reset every so-few hours?

Comment: Out of curiosity - why use shared memory to store the value rather than APC or memcache? Change to approach might be better than determining why the memory segment is released.

Comment: @N.B. :I've never used memcache or APC before. I thought the shm would be good for the purpose.
@ Michael: I've not checked that yet. I can add such a code.
@ Roy: Nothing I'm aware of resets the apache process regularly

Comment: @Roy: shm is implemented at the system level, not application level.

Comment: @John - it's difficult to determine why the memory is being freed (it might not be, since we don't have the access to your machine - it's difficult to guess what could be happening). Personally, I'd use the caching mechanisms designed for such purpose to persist variables between requests. One of them is APC, and the usage is nearly exactly the same as with shm_* so there would be no learning curve involved.